# C++ dispatch table with templated functions

Tags: c++

I have a dispatch table in some C++ code.  It maps tags to functions that can process those tags.  In the first version, it takes functions that accept two strings and return a string.  The strings are serialised protobufs.

```
map<string, function<string(const string& serialised_1,
                            const string& serialised_2)>> converters = {
...
{ 'dog', ProcessTwoDogs },
{ 'cat', ProcessTwoCats },
...
};
```

Here the converter functions look like this

```
string ProcessTwoDogs(const string& dog_1_str, const string& dog_2_str);
```

After implementing quite a number of these converters, I realised they were often over half boilerplate: error checking, deserialisation, serialisation, etc.  So I wrote a quick template that vastly simplifies my code:

```
template <typename ProtoT>
std::string ConvertProtos(
    const std::string& proto_str_a,
    const std::string& proto_str_b,
    std::function<ProtoT(const ProtoT&, const ProtoT&)> convert_proto) {
    ProtoT proto_a = ...;
    ProtoT probo_b = ...;
    // and various error checks.
    ProtoT proto_out = convert_proto(proto_a, proto_b);
    // some more checks, and serialise to proto_out_str.
    return proto_out_str;
}
```

And now `convert_proto()` can look like this:

```
Dog ProcessTwoDogs(const Dog& dog_1, const Dog& dog_2) { ... }
```

This is very nice, but now I've broken the dispatch table, because each animal processor has a different signature, since a `Dog` and a `Cat` are both protobufs but otherwise are unrelated.  I don't know how to make a dispatch table without resorting to a long bit of `if ... else if ....`.

What I want is a map like this:

```
// Doesn't compile.
map<string, 
   template<typename ProtoT>function<ProtoT(const ProtoT&, const ProtoT&)>>
```

Then my function that uses the dispatch table, which currently says something like

```
auto processor = the_map.at(tag);
string new_string = processor(string_1, string_2);
```

becomes

```
auto processor = the_map.at(tag);
string new_string = ConvertProtobufs(string_1, string_2, processor);
```

Of course, one way would be to define an abstract base class with `operator()` that takes strings, and then implement an instance of that class for each of my conversion function.  The `operator()` calls some function that is only defined in the derived classes.  But now I've lost any gain in readability or conciseness I might have found.

Any suggestions?

### Update

Following a line of reasoning proposed by @felix, I wrote this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::function;
using std::endl;
using std::map;
using std::string;

struct Dog {
    void operator()() { cout << "I am a dog." << endl; }
};
struct Cat {
    void operator()() { cout << "I am a cat." << endl; }
};

string cat = string("cat");
string dog = string("dog");

template<string& s> void fn() { cout << "I am lost" << endl; }
template<> void fn<dog>() { Dog dog; dog(); }
template<> void fn<cat>() { Cat cat; cat(); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    fn<dog>();
    fn<cat>();
    // Oops, it all falls apart here:
    string dog1("dog");
    fn<dog1>();   // Doesn't compile, and a dog is not a dog1.
}
```

The problem in the above is that the template arguments must of course be known at compile time.  That's fine when I'm using const string's from an ontology of strings, but fails if the strings pass through a database and so the lookup is dynamic based on value rather than object.

Comment: Can you add an hypotetical usage example on how you want to use `MergeProtos` and on how the final syntax would look like?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I've modified the question to offer a more detailed example.

Comment: @hma: do you know all of the `tag` strings at compile-time? (I.e. do you expect to add new functions to the lookup map at run-time?)

Comment: I know them all at compile time.  But there are 30 or so of them, so a table is easier to grok than a morass of `if-then`'s.

Comment: generic lambda expression might help.

Comment: @felix Maybe, but what would the map statement look like?  I can't use auto as a map template argument, and just because the lambdas all look the same (use auto) doesn't they have the same type.

Comment: @jma take a look at [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-quickstart-any). Given a boost::any, the goal is to dispatch to the function associated to the dynamic type of the any. It's totally different from your original design, but they seem share the same goal.

Comment: I've clarified the question and added a non-example.  If the help you've kindly offered isn't helping me, it's surely been my fault by inadequately posing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still want `map<string, function<string(const string&, const string&)>>`, you just want to populate it differently:

```
using converter = function<string(const string&, const string&)>;

map<string, converter> converters = {
    ...
   { "dog", convert_protos(ProcessTwoDogs) },
   { "cat", convert_protos(ProcessTwoCats) },
    ...
};
```

Now you want a function template returning a converter that you can use with any of `ProcessTwoDogs`, `ProcessTwoCats` and what have you.

```
template <typename P_Res, typename P_A, typename P_B> 
converter convert_protos(P_Res (*processor)(P_A, P_B)) {

    return [](const string& s_a, const string& s_b) -> string
       {
          // some error checks
          P_A p_a = deserialize<P_A>(s_a);
          P_B p_b = deserialize<P_B>(s_a);
          // some more error checks
          P_Res p_res = processor(p_a, p_b);
          // yet more checks
          string s_res = serialize(p_res);
          // last final checks
          return s_res;
       };
}
```

Comment: That's it.  Thanks.  I'd tried a minor variant on this and given up in the face of some errors, the most important of which is maybe worth modifying above: the template argument can't be deduced.  And I can't see my way clear of using a lambda.  So in the map I think one must write `[](const string& x, const string& y) { return convert_protos<Dog>(x, y, ProcessTwoDogs); }`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't helping, it will eventually lead to reflection (which is totally unnecessary). I didn't realize this until I see your update.

### The original answer:

I am not sure whether I have fully understood your question.

A solution is to use member function template and function template explicit instantiation.

```
#include <cassert>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Dog {};
class Cat {};

struct Processor {
  template <class T>
  T process(const T &, const T &) const;

  const std::string tag_;
};

template <>
Dog Processor::process(const Dog &, const Dog &) const {
  std::cout << "dog" << std::endl;
  return Dog{};
}

template <>
Cat Processor::process(const Cat &, const Cat &) const {
  assert(tag_ == "cat");
  std::cout << "cat" << std::endl;
  return Cat{};
}

int main() {
  std::map<std::string, Processor> mapa =
      {{"dog", Processor{"dog"}},
       {"cat", Processor{"cat"}} };

  mapa["cat"].process(Cat{}, Cat{});

  return 0;
}
```

And if you don't need any tag check, you can remove the member variable tag_ and make processor a static class, but this would make map in fact not needed any more.

The class `Processor` has a member function template, which is explicitly instantied for `Cat` and `Dog`.

Informally, when calling `process` on any instance of `Processor` with argument type `Cat`, the compiler will find that the function template `process` has an explicit instantion for type `Cat`. Then, instead of implicitly instantiate a member function, the compiler will use the explicit one, aka `Cat Processor::process(const Cat &, const Cat &) const`.

Comment: Thanks, @felix.  But I don't quite see how that dispatch works.  Neither does my compiler, which complains `error: explicit specialization of 'process' in class scope` at `Dog process(const Dog &, const Dog &) const {` and at `Cat process(const Cat &, const Cat &) const {`.

Comment: Seems your compiler is following C++03 standard. I have edited the code snippet, it should work now.

Comment: And I have provided a rough explanation for explaining how it works. This is the best I can do, I don't know how exactly the compiler works with template, it's quite complicated, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments.  (I compile with -std=c++14: same errors from g++ and from clang++.)  That code works.  Well done.  Now that I understand it, a minor problem: what I have in main are serialised protobufs.  Until I resolve the key from the map, I don't know what type they should deserialise to.  Your solution, while very clever, embeds that knowledge in the arguments.